# Pygame shuffle the input code

Tags: python-2.7, pygame

I am an absolute Pygame newbie. I wanted to make a little test, which take an input from the user and shuffles the order of its letters, until accidentaly the correct order is catched again. Then it shoud make a little sily show with the word, waiting for the user to close the window. I don't know how to do the last part of the programm (doing the show and waiting for the `QUIT` event). The version i have now is after catching the correct letter-order do the show for 8 seconds and then `pygame.quit()`.

the code is as follows, the part i am talking about beginns in the block:
`if shuffledWord == word:`

```
# Shuffle a word...
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import random
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

word = raw_input("Typ a name...\n") #get the word to play with
wordLen = len(word) * 100 + (len(word) - 1) * 10 + 200  # in pixel
screen_size = (wordLen, 400)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)
font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 200)

runs = True


while runs:
     for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == QUIT:
            runs = False

    listedWord = [x for x in word] #shuffle the word and send it for rendering
    random.shuffle(listedWord)
    shuffledWord = "".join(listedWord)
    txtRightOn = font.render("-" + shuffledWord + "-", True, (random.randint(
    0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255)))
    txtRightOff = font.render("." + shuffledWord + ".", True, (random.randint(
    0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255)))
    txtWrong = font.render(shuffledWord, True, (random.randint(
    0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255)))

    if shuffledWord == word: #if got the correct word again: do this little show here!
        for i in range(10):
            screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
            screen.blit(txtRightOn, (0, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.wait(400)
            screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
            screen.blit(txtRightOff, (0, 100))
            pygame.display.update()
            pygame.time.wait(400)
        pygame.quit()

    else:
        pygame.time.wait(450)
        screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
        screen.blit(txtWrong, (0, 100))
        pygame.display.update()


pygame.quit()
```

PS: besides is any suggestions to make this script more efficient and better from the pygamic-point of view is highly appreciated.

Comment: btw: you can use `list(word)` instead of `[x for x in word]`

Comment: you can use text variable `state` to decide which part of code should be executed -"shuffling", "displaying RightOn",  "displaying RightOff", "waiting for user quit". Or you can use many boolean (True/False) variables 'state_shuffling', etc., 'state_waiting` - similar to `runs` variable.

Comment: btw: you have to render `txtRightOn`,  `txtRightOff` only `if shuffledWord == word`

Comment: can you show a little abstract example of what you mean in your second comment?

Answer (score 1):

I created working example with `state` and `time` to control which part of code should be executed - but this doesn't stop `while runs` loop and `for event` loop.

```
import pygame
import random

word = raw_input("Typ a name...\n") #get the word to play with
wordLen = len(word) * 100 + (len(word) - 1) * 10 + 200  # in pixel
screen_size = (wordLen, 400)

# --- init ---

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(screen_size)

font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 200)

# --- mainloop ---

runs = True
state = 'shuffle'

while runs:

    current_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            runs = False

    if state == 'shuffle':
        listedWord = list(word)
        random.shuffle(listedWord)
        shuffledWord = "".join(listedWord)
        if shuffledWord == word:
            txtRightOn = font.render("-" + shuffledWord + "-", True, (random.randint(
            0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255)))
            txtRightOff = font.render("." + shuffledWord + ".", True, (random.randint(
            0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255)))

            # change state
            txt = txtRightOn
            state = 'show_right_on'
            state_time = current_time + 400
            state_repeat = 10
        else:
            # change state
            txt = font.render(shuffledWord, True, (random.randint(
        0, 255), random.randint(0, 255), random.randint(0, 255)))
            state = 'show_wrong'
            state_time = current_time + 450

    if state == 'show_right_on':
        if state_time <= current_time:
            # change state
            txt = txtRightOff
            state = 'show_right_off'
            state_time = current_time + 400

    if state == 'show_right_off':
        if state_time <= current_time:
            # change state
            txt = txtRightOn
            state = 'show_right_on'
            state_time = current_time + 400
            state_repeat -= 1
        if state_repeat == 0:
            # change state
            state = 'wait for quit'
            print('DEBUG: wait for quit')

    if state == 'show_wrong':
        if state_time <= current_time:
            # change state
            state = 'shuffle'

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    screen.blit(txt, (0, 100))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```